Integrating custom tags using GTM on Substack
I have a substack blog and I am hoping to have a Quantcast pixel running on it. Since substack doesn't allow direct HTML customisation, but allows for Google Tag Manager integrations (literally just accepting the GTM id and not code), I hoped that I can use GTM to set up my Quantcast Pixel.
When I do so however, the Quantcast Pixels don't fire. Initially I thought GTM itself wasn't working properly, but saw that Google Analytics pixels using the same route were firing.
Using the GTM debug mode, I eventually came across the following Data Layer values for all the events:
{
  gtm: {
    allowlist: ["google"],
    blocklist: [
      "customPixels",
      "customScripts",
      "html",
      "nonGooglePixels",
      "nonGoogleScripts",
      "nonGoogleIframes",
      "sandboxedScripts"
    ],
    uniqueEventId: 1,
    start: 1717779402480
  },
  event: "gtm.js",
  userId: "21720474"
}

From GTM documentation, it looks like the allowlist and blocklist variables are what are likely causing the Quantcast pixels not to fire, while allowing GA pixels to be fired. I checked my own GTM set up and it doesn't feel like there is any place I have set up the allowlist and blocklist fields. It seems to be emanating from substack itself where they set up this data layer before initialising GTM.
Questions:
Without customising the JS on the page, is there a way to tell GTM to override Data Layer, or somehow force a default value before initialising?
Alternatively, any substack experts who know how to alter the Data Layer value such that the non-google tags will be allowed?

I think it is blocked by Substack.
Looks like they forbid you to implement and html tag in the GTM.
Then of course you can not add Quantcast pixels in custom html tag.
You can confirmed with Substack about this.
